# Prompt for sudo password and programmatically elevate privilege in bash script?

Tags: bash, sudo

I'm currently working on a bash script that installs and sets up various programs on a stock Linux system (currently, Ubuntu). Because it installs programs and copies a number of files to various folders that require elevated privileges, I've already done the standard "I need elevated privileges"-and-exit.

However, I would like, if possible, to be able to prompt the user for their sudo password and elevate the script's privileges automatically if the user doesn't run the script command with sudo (such as launching it from the GUI file manager), without the user having to restart the script.

As this is designed to run on stock Linux installs, any option that modifies the system won't work for my purposes. All options need to be contained to the script itself.

Is this possible within Bash? If so, what's the best (secure, yet concise) way to do this?

Comment: See also on AU: [How to execute a script as super user first checking the user and getting pass from askpass if not super user](http://askubuntu.com/q/30181/1769)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Ah, the joys of having so many niche sites while trying to minimize fragmentation. And you know, the link you gave never once came up for me while searching Google.

Comment: Also see [How to enter password only once in a bash script needing sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/711580), [Request root privilege from within a script](https://askubuntu.com/q/746350),[Create a sudo user in script with no prompt for password...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43853533/608639), [sudo with password in one command line?](https://superuser.com/a/67766/173513), [How to prompt user for sudo password?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47538572/608639), etc

Comment: @jww you do realize that nearly all of those links were asked about 4 years *after* this one, right?

Comment: @Shauna - I'm guessing you have solved the problem by now. The links are for future visitors.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I run `sudo` directly from the script:

```
if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi
```

Comment: This will throw an error if `EUID` is not set for any reason – better quote it: `[ "$EUID" != 0 ]`

Comment: For those wondering: `EUID` (“effective user ID”) can be changed with [`setuid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) while `UID` can not.

Comment: It seems that something like `sudo "$BASH_SOURCE" $(printf '%q ' "$@")` is a safer alternative, according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640403/4642212#comment60404297_24640403).

Comment: @SebastianSimon but it's bash-specific, while the script in the answer is POSIX-compliant

Comment: @SebastianSimon Do you know what `"$0" "$@"` actually gets wrong? The comment you linked claims it fails on whitespace and glob characters due to splicing an array into a string, but that is not true in my testing, and I thought the whole point of the special handling bash does with `"$@"` (rather than `$@` or `$*`) is that it specifically handles properly expanding into a series of arguments with exactly the same contents, (regardless of whitespace within any of the arguments).

Answer (score 25):

Add this as the first line of the script:

```
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo bash "$0" "$@"
```

Change `sudo` to `gksu` or `gksudo` if you prefer a graphical prompt.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on Debian, where there seems to be no sudo command?

Comment: @wrongusername install `sudo`, it's much better than using `su`. But if you really want, probably `exec su -c "$0" "$@"`

Comment: This also won't inherit any environment variables from the current shell; use `exec sudo -E bash "$0" "$@"` to get that behavior.

Answer (score 18):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (($EUID != 0)); then
  if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
  else
    exec 1>output_file
    gksu "$0 $@"
  fi
  exit
fi

# some example stuff
ls -l /root
echo "app: $0"
for f; do
  echo ">$f<"
done
```

Comment: What does `if [[ -t 1 ]];` check for?

Comment: Ah, ok. I figured it had something to do with terminal vs GUI, but wasn't sure what the if statement itself was checking.

Answer (score 4):

An example script that I don't mind sharing::

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@" && echo -n "sudo bash what: "
read WHAT
sudo $WHAT
```

Comment: `[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"` -- Looks like a really efficient one liner! Nice!

Comment: Would it make sense to use Effective UID here, `$EUDI`, or always the same outcome? E.g., `[[ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"`

Answer (score 0):

I use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file as follows:

- In the line with your user, add this next to the username:

  ```
  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
  ```

  then save.
- When that user

  ```
  sudo su -
  ```

  he will be logged on as root without entering a password.