# Echo while waiting for sudo prompt

Tags: sudo

### Context

I am using [this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28791/prompt-for-sudo-password-and-programmatically-elevate-privilege-in-bash-script) of elevating permissions in a script if not run as a root.

My Bash script checks for the presence of a certain file it needs to use:

```
if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
    if [ -f "/foo/bar" ]
    then
        AGE=$(expr `date +%s` - `stat -c %Y "/foo/bar"`)
        echo "/foo/bar is here, ${AGE}s old"
    else
        echo "/foo/bar not there (yet?)"
    fi

    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi

# the rest of the script, needs /foo/bar
```

So if a non-root runs this, and there is the file, the response is like this `/foo/bar is here, 27s old`. Otherwise, the response is `/foo/bar is not there (yet?)`. Then, the `sudo` prompt runs.

Now the question is: in the second case, when `/foo/bar` is not ready yet, is there a way to notify the user once `/foo/bar` appears? The user would type the password and see "oh the file is there" or "better wait before I hit Return".

There are two parts of this, *detect a file has appeared in the file system* (not asking about this one), and *echo something while the sudo prompt is up*.

### Question

I am interested in the second part. Is it possible to write something to the output, above or below the sudo prompt, "asynchronously"?

Comment: Use `inotify` to detect that the file has appeared.

Comment: Question: Why display the sudo prompt at all if the user is not meant to press RETURN at that point?  Why not just wait until the file is ready and then run sudo?

Comment: The file is going to appear in the span of the few seconds while the user is typing the password. The sequence of steps could be rearranged I guess, first ask for sudo, then wait until the file appears - meaning "don't foo the bar" would be a valid answer here. However, I really do want to find out if it's possible to asynchronously let the user know while the sudo prompt is there.

Comment: I posted an answer to the second part of the question.  It would be nice to post that as a separate question (or edit this one to leave only the second part).

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks, I was trying to provide some context. I made the question a bit clearer to focus on the real question. Thanks for the answer, I will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the second part of the question, how to write messages while waiting at the `sudo` prompt:

```bash
trap '2>/dev/null' CHLD
(sleep 5; echo; echo "New spam has just arrived!") &
MSGPID=$!
sudo -v
wait $MSGPID
trap - CHLD
```

`sleep 5` in the subshell simulates the message arriving asynchronously.  The first `echo` just makes sure the message doesn't end up next to the `Password:` prompt.  It also works when writing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

The first `trap` is there to kill the messages about the status of the background job.  `waitpid` and the second `trap` cancel the effects of the first `trap`.

Bad things happen if the command in the subshell exits before having a chance to return a meaningful PID (can happen on some OSes, hopefully not too many these days).